# Why are balls in the taxicab metric always hyperoctahedrons?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, convex-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Let $\ell_1^n$ be the space $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the $L_1$, i.e., taxicab metric.

When $n=2$, a unit ball is a square with sides parallel to $45^\circ$.

When $n=3$, we get an octahedron, which looks like two pyramids glued together along their bottoms.

For general $n$, it's stated in [various places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry#Balls) that metric balls take the shape of an $n$-orthoplex, also called an $n$-cross-polytope, or also a hyperoctahedron.

However, I can't find a proof of this anywhere, though I did find many articles about various other aspects of so-called "taxicab geometry" like how the equivalent of $\pi$ is $4$, how to make ellipses, etc.

How can one show that taxicab balls take the form of an orthoplex?

Comment: The Wikipedia article simply defines the $n$-orthoplex to be the unit ball in the $\ell^1$ metric, and this seems like the cleanest and most parsimonious definition to me. Do you have a different definition that you want to compare this to?

Comment: I see. I was more looking for an explanation of why the $\ell^1$ unit ball has this particular shape, instead of a different shape. I can see why clearly in the plane, but I don't see why it is the case for general $n$.

Comment: [This article](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Orthoplex) has a more involved definition using $(n-1)$-simplices connecting pairs of vertices.

Comment: Would you be happy with an argument that the unit ball of the $\ell^1$ metric is the convex hull of the points $(0, 0, \dots, \pm 1, \dots, 0)$? That's pretty straightforward to show.

Comment: Yes - that's a good way of looking at it and helpful for my intuition.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question to make explicit what definiton you have oof an orthoplex...