# How many $(d-1)$-dimensional hyperplanes are the facets of the $d$-hyperoctahedron parallel to?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry, polyhedra

This question is related to research I am doing on intersection graphs of convex polytopes in Euclidean space.

The following definition comes from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2018.03.046):

> For any polytope $P$, let $\dim P$ denote its dimension. Let $\mathcal L^d$ be the set of all $(d-1)$-dimensional hyperplanes in $\mathbb R^d$, containing the origin.
> By ${\mathcal L^d \choose k}$ we denote the set of all $k$-element
> subsets of $\mathcal L^d$. For any $L \in {\mathcal L^d \choose k}$,
> by $\mathcal P^d (L)$ we denote the set of all polytopes in $\mathbb R^d$ whose every facet is parallel to one of the hyperplanes in $L$.

Given a regular [hyperoctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope) $H_d$ in $\mathbb R^d$, what is the smallest $k$ such that $H$ belongs to $\mathcal P^d (L)$ for some $L \in {\mathcal L^d \choose k}$?

Looking at small examples like $d=2,3$, we have that $H_2$ is a square, so in that case $k=2$ (the facets of $H_2$ are parallel to $2$ lines). For $H_3$, the upper half has $4$ faces parallel to $4$ planes in $\mathbb R^3$, but by symmetry the faces of the bottom half are also parallel to those $4$, so $k=4$.

In general, $H_d$ has $2^d$ facets, but by symmetry I think the answer should be $k=2^d /2$. When $d=2,3$ this checks out.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Short answer: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyperoctahedron is the convex hull of the $2d$ points with all but one coordinate $0$, the other $\pm 1$.

The facets are the hyperplanes
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d \epsilon_ix_i = \pm 1
$$
where each $\epsilon_1 = \pm 1$.

For each of the $2^d$ ways to choose those signs the hyperplanes where the sum is $\pm 1$ are parallel, so there are $2^{d-1}$ parallel pairs.

PS  I think this may   answer  your previous question at [Why are balls in the taxicab metric always hyperoctahedrons?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4638621/why-are-balls-in-the-taxicab-metric-always-hyperoctahedrons)